# compose sql to be executed parsing results from find + exec

Tags: mysql, bash, find

I have a bunch of folders and I want to create a database per folder (getting only directory name using basename). I've tried to compose such a sentence using find + exec to no avail.

```
find /path/to/folder/namedb -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec 'mysql -u root -pMyPass -e create database if not exists basename {}' \;
```

what I get is:

```
mysql -u root -pMyPass -e create database if not exists basename /path/to/folder/media
mysql -u root -pMyPass -e create database if not exists basename /path/to/folder/news
mysql -u root -pMyPass -e create database if not exists basename /path/to/folder/security
```

what i expect is:

```
mysql -u root -pMyPass -e create database if not exists media
mysql -u root -pMyPass -e create database if not exists news
mysql -u root -pMyPass -e create database if not exists security
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `bash -c` with `find ... -exec ...`:

```
find /path/to/folder/namedb -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d \
  -exec bash -c 'mysql -u root -pMyPass -e create database if not exists "$1"' _ $(basename {}) \;
```